# How to break while loop android server?

Tags: android

This is part of server's code. I got problem, that i can't break this endless loop. It's separate class, which handle client connections. How it's possible to make unlimited quantity of clients connected, but finish connection on button click if it's possible?

```
public class Handler implements Runnable {

public void run(){
....
//sockets
try{
....
//socket

while (true) {

    client = server.accept();
    count++;
    Log.d("My Log", "Connected");
    Log.d("My Log", "log" + count);
    executor.execute(new Handler(client));
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
while(true)
```

use something like

```
while(myConditional)
{
    client = server.accept();
    count++;
    Log.d("My Log", "Connected");
    Log.d("My Log", "log" + count);
    executor.execute(new Handler(client));
}
```

where myConditional is a boolean value that you can set in the UI thread, something like

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        myConditional = false;
    }
});
```